# how to share Alamofire in widget

Tags: ios, widget, cocoapods, alamofire, today-extension

I'm making some weather app. and i want to show weather info on widget too

So i tried to import Alamofire in Widget's ViewController but it couldn't find module

I also check tutorial from other blog or website, but in my project i cannot find Alamofire in `Linked Frameworks and Libraries like this

[image]

This is my Podfile

```
  platform :ios, '10.0'

   target 'From Yesterday' do
     use_frameworks!
     pod 'Alamofire'
     pod 'SVProgressHUD'
     pod "ScalingCarousel"
   end
```

I also edit Pod file like below

```
  platform :ios, '10.0'
  use_frameworks!
   target 'From Yesterday' do
     use_frameworks!
     pod 'Alamofire'
     pod 'SVProgressHUD'
     pod "ScalingCarousel"
   end
   target 'From Yesterday Widget' do
     pod 'Alamofire'
   end
```

but it gaves me some warning not error, I think that means i installed Pods twice so I think this is wrong

How can i use Alamofire correctly in Widget